# How to store data in mysql from ios app using php?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I want to save user registration detail from my ios app (using swift 3) in MySQL using PHP. But it's not working. 
Here is my code:

**registeruser.php**

```
$response = array ();
    if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // getting values
    $username = $_POST ["username"];
    $password = $_POST ['password'];
    // including the db operation file
    require_once '../include/DbOperation.php';
    // inserting values
    if ($db->createUser($username, $password)) {
        $response ['error'] = false;
        $response ['message'] = 'user added successfully';
    } else {
        $response ['error'] = true;
        $response ['message'] = ' user not added';
    }
echo json_encode ( $response );
 public function createUser($username, $password)
    {
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registerUser(username, password) values(?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("register", $username, $password);  
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo $result;
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I don't know why it's not working?

the **error** shown is

> Undefined index: Username and password.

Comment: You are trying to access $_POST at the username index. There exists no value set for that index. (and password as well) Thus you are receiving that error message. This is an indication that you are not properly issuing a POST request to your endpoint (your script in this case)

Comment: you have to check the code usin postman before doing

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionXXX() 
{
    $response = array ();
    if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        // getting values
        $username = $_POST ["username"];
        $password = $_POST ['password'];
        // including the db operation file
        require_once '../include/DbOperation.php';
        // inserting values
        // $db = new ***
        if ($db->createUser($username, $password)) {
            $response ['error'] = false;
            $response ['message'] = 'user added successfully';
        } else {
            $response ['error'] = true;
            $response ['message'] = 'user not added';
        }
        return json_encode($response);
    }
}
public function createUser($username, $password)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registerUser(username, password) values(?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("register", $username, $password);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```